# Are there other words like "gratuité" that are nouns in French but not in English?

Tags: noms

On the provincial student loans brochures that I am reading, the French version says "Gratuité des frais de scolarité pour les étudiantes et étudiants admissible", and the English version says "Free Tuition for eligible students".

Using Wordreference, I translated "Gratuité des frais de scolarité" literally as "[Something free] of fees of education".

Wordreference's [entry](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/gratuit%C3%A9%20des%20frais) for "gratuité" surprised me, though:

> gratuité nf   (fait de ne pas être payant)    free adj
>   Note: There is no
>   noun in English. "Gratuité" will always be translated with the
>   adjective "free", as in "free education", or "free room" in a hotel
>   offer.

Questions:
1. Are there other French nouns that have no corresponding noun in English?
2. I had guessed that "gratuité" was an adjective, because it looked like a past participle, because it ended in "é". Are words ending in "é" most often past participles, or are they often instead nouns?
3. Why is it "des frais", but "de scolarité"? That is, why is it "des" for one of the words, but "de" for the other word?

Comment: *Volant* = driving wheel

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Are there other French nouns that have no corresponding noun in English?

Yes I guess many other exist (depaysement for example)

> 2. I had guessed that "gratuité" was an adjective, because it looked like a past participle, because it ended in "é". Are words ending in
>      "é" most often past participles, or are they often instead nouns?

Many other word finish with é (or ée) matinée, lycée, amitié, liberté, volonté ... So yeah, words finishing with é are not all adjectives.

> 3. Why is it "des frais", but "de scolarité"? That is, why is it "des" for one of the words, but "de" for the other word?

Because "frais" is a plural and "scolarité" is singular. There are many fees for that particular thing.

Comment: 3) but if the reason is that "scolarité" is singular, should it not be "de la scolarité", instead of "de scolarité"?

Comment: 1) actually, WordReference does have an entry for dépaysement, where there are corresponding English nouns as translations! (http://www.wordreference.com/fren/d%C3%A9paysement)

Comment: It is *frais de scolarité* and not *frais de la scolarité* because we are not talking about a well-identfied *scolarité*: it could be any *scolarité*. Same as eg *jus de pomme*, *maison de campagne*, *cours de français*, *livre de cuisine*, etc.

Comment: @Greg but then why is it "des frais" instead of "de frais"?

Comment: Because *frais* is in the plural and it is not just any *frais*, they are well-identified: so in "gratuité des frais de scolarité", *des* is the contractions for *de les*. Note also that *les frais* in the sense of "expenses, costs" is always used in the plural in French.

Answer (score -2):

> Are there other French nouns that have no corresponding noun in English?

The verb "se défenestrer" which means passing somebody through a window doesn't exist in english I believe. So the noun "Défenestration" probably doesn't exist either.